# Does theme update also update a child theme zip

Tags: themes, child-theme, updates, parent-theme

Total wordpress beginner here. I purchased a organicfood theme and when I got an updated version for it, among other files I also found organicfood child theme zip in main directory.

I know that organicfood.zip contains the updated version of parent theme but I don't know if same goes for organicfood child theme zip. Is the child zip added with every update just so that a new buyer has that default child theme template?

Answer (score 1):

We use a theme which updates in a similar manner, we get an almost empty child theme with our package.

It's basically got a child theme folder with a blank functions.php so it's literally just a template for new people. However, personally, I make use of this folder by copying the files I need from the parent theme and working on them with the changes I require in the child theme.

If your theme ships with any more files in that folder, eg header.php, it's worth checking them as they may have updates correlating to the new parent theme, but I've never seen a theme ship with a child theme that has more files in. If so then great you should have your template and can edit the files as you need without copying them over.

Answer (score 1):

WordPress parent theme are the main file which contains all data and coding.

If you directly edit everything in the parent theme such as CSS, functions and any other pages then it might be possible to lose many of previously made changes when you will update to new version of that theme. So, it is a good practice to use child theme to be safe from any update.

The child theme does not get updated when you update Parent Theme.

In your case, as you mentioned organicfood.zip is the parent theme which also contains a child theme zip file. You are lucky that already you have child theme. So, you can just start editing in your child theme.

Many WordPress theme does not provide child theme zip file. In that case, you have to create child theme and edit file according to your requirement. So that, next time when you will update your parent theme then you will not loose your design and other changes which you have made in your child theme.

Comment: Most of the time with a theme update (especially big ones) you'll have to update the child theme anyway? You may have code which is no longer functional with the parent theme, its settings, its new functionality?

Comment: Yes you are right Mr @Aravona